# Accessing a Class property without using dot operator

Tags: c#, oop, operator-overloading

I need to overload some operators when called using Double types. To achieve this, I'm creating a class MyDouble, which inherits from Double. MyDouble looks somewhat like this

```
class MyDouble : Double
{
   Double value;
   // operator overloads go here
}
```

I want to abstract away the `value` property from the user so that it is usable just as a Double. Basically I want the user to be able to do this:

```
MyDouble a = 5;         //a.value gets assigned 5
Console.WriteLine(a);   //prints a.value
```

I don't want the user to have to specifically target the `value` property. Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Comment: not very clear your purpose, override the ToString function?

Comment: As an example, say I want to overload the `<` operator. So, if you use the binary operator `<` my overloaded definition will decide the return result.

Comment: What is this "Double" class from which MyDouble inherits?  It can't be System.Double, because that's a value type, and value types are implicitly sealed.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I could derive from System.Double but realized it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an implicit conversion operator, like this:

```
class MyDouble {
    public Value {get; private set;}
    public Double(double value) {
        Value = value;
    }
    // Other declarations go here...
    public static implicit operator double(MyDouble md) {
        return md.Value;
    }
    public static implicit operator MyDouble(double d) {
        return new MyDouble(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. Upvoting, and implementing. I'll be back to accept. Thank you!

Comment: This isn't working exactly as I expected. If I do `Mydouble a = 5.0`, I expect an instance of MyDouble `a` to be created with `a.value = 5`, however I get a 'Cannot implicitly convert type double to MyDouble'. Seems like I'm not overloading the correct operator.

Comment: What's going on here?  How are you inheriting from a value type?

Comment: I have added a follow up question in case you'd like to have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494871/casting-my-class-to-int64-double-etc

Comment: @phoog Oops, I've been copy-pasting too much! Thanks for spotting the error!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight *whew* what a relief.  I was nearly asleep and I half thought that something had gone terribly wrong with the universe!