# Casting my Class to Int64, Double etc

Tags: c#, oop, operator-overloading

Related question: [Accessing a Class property without using dot operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494070/accessing-a-class-property-without-using-dot-operator/)

I've created a class called `MyDouble` looks like this

```
class MyDouble
{
  double value;
  //overloaded operators and methods
}
```

I am able to do all kinds of operations on MyDouble. Examples:

```
MyDouble a = 5.0;
a += 3.0;
...etc
```

However, this still throws an error

```
MyDouble a = 5.0;
long b = (Int64)a;  //error
long b = (int64)a.value; //works
```

How can I define it such that an operation like `(Int64)a` automatically converts to `(Int64)a.value` ? I don't want the user to ever have to worry about the existence of the `value` property.

Comment: Why do you use both `long` and `Int64`? One is an aloas for the other and I think the more idiomatic way is to use the aliases if they exist instead of the type names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for this conversion to work, you would need an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to Int64.

This would look like:

```
class MyDouble
{
    double value;

    public static explicit operator Int64(MyDouble value)
    {
         return (Int64)value.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it have to be explicit? An implicit conversion works as well and the cast becomes optional.

Comment: @Jay You *could* do an implicit operation, but the OP showed including the conversion operator.  Personally, I tend to try to avoid implicit conversions unless they make a lot of sense (implicitly converting from double to long seems like a bad idea, though).

Comment: I did leave the casts explicit where precision or data loss might be an issue. However, I made the cast to Double implicit since my class is basically just a Double.

Comment: @Jay please see my edited answer for reasons why the conversion should be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

There's an explicit conversion from double to Int64, but not from your class to Int64.  all you need to do is define one.  Or, if you have a conversion from your class to double, which I suppose you do, you could do this:

long x = (long)(double)a;

However, that's cumbersome; I'd define the explicit conversion operator.

The conversion should be explicit, not implicit, unless you have a good reason for making it explicit.

The language-defined conversion from double to long is explicit *because the conversion could cause information loss.*  You can lose information with this conversion because there are some doubles, like 0.5, *that do not convert exactly to long.*  This is called a *narrowing conversion*.

With language-defined conversions, narrowing conversions are explicit.  If they were implicit, programmers could accidentally lose information by assigning a value of one type to a variable of another type.  Defining this conversion as implicit violates that entirely sensible principle, so there would have to be some compelling case for doing so.

Here's an example showing the value of this principle.  If narrowing conversions were implicit, it would make code more brittle.  Assume that double-to-int conversion is implicit:

```
class Family
{
    ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

int GetAverageNumberOfChildren(IEnumerable<Family> families)
{
    return families.Sum(f => f.Children.Count) / families.Count();
}

void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<Family> families)
{
    int averageNumberOfChildren = GetAverageNumberOfChildren(families);
    //...
}
```

Oops!  We have a bug!  `GetAverageNumberOfChildren` should return a double!  Let's fix it!

```
double GetAverageNumberOfChildren(IEnumerable<Family> families)
{
    return families.Average(f => f.Children.Count);
}
```

Whew, everything compiles and runs!  Sure glad we caught that bug!

But, sadly, no.  *We still have a bug!*  `SomeMethod` implicitly converts the double to an int, so where the expected value might be `2.4`, the actual value is `2`.

Because double-to-int conversion is *explicit*, the compiler saves us from ourselves.  After we fix  `GetAverageNumberOfChildren`, *the erroneous program does not compile.*

Now, if your `MyDouble` class had some validation that restricted it to integer values with a range equal to or smaller than the range of `long`, then you would be safe to make the conversion implicit.  But in that case, of course, you should be using `long`, not `double`.

Answer (score 1):

An implicit conversion will work as well as an explicit conversion.

```
public static implicit operator long(MyDouble m)
{
    return (long) m.value;
}
```

With this in place you can do:

```
long b = (Int64) a;
```

or just

```
long b = a;
```

This is just to illustrate that the conversion need not be explicit. As noted, however, it *should* be explicit because of the potential for data loss.

Comment: This is true, but dangerous. See my edited answer for an explanation.

Comment: @phoog I understand. I was only taking issue with the "you *need* an explicit conversion" language.

Comment: Fair enough; I just thought that if we're discussing the existence of implicit conversions, it would be wise to discuss the reasons for making narrowing conversions explicit.  Otherwise someone might be tempted to implement a conversion that should be explicit as an implicit conversion "because it is easier" or "because it makes my code cleaner", without considering the increased likelihood of writing buggy programs.